# python get/set class variable inside class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I do not know how to access a class object inside another class object. 
Given a class "Best Result" which consists of

1. an integer value
2. an array of class "Color"

As shown in the code below. My questions are:

(A) In class "Best Result" def "SetColors", how to initialize self.colors to size of colors? The code below seems to assign empty list, so when I copy param "colors" to "self.colors" it said "index out of range". Also, is deepcopy the right way?

```
  self.colors = list(colors)
  for i in range(0, len(colors)):
    self.colors[i]= copy.deepcopy(colors[i])
```

(B) How to set and get array of class "Color" inside class "Best Result"?

---

Thanks for the comment, I tried to refine the code and got the answer for my questions below.

---

```
import copy

class Color(object):
    __elems__ = "num", "nodelist"

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0                    
        self.nodelist = []              

    def items(self):
        return [
            (field_name, getattr(self, field_name)) 
             for field_name in self.__elems__]

class BestResult(object):
    __elems__ = "objfunc", "colors"

    def __init__(self):
        self.objfunc = 0        
        self.colors = []              

    def setObjFunc(self, value):
        if value < self.objfunc:
            self.objfunc = value

    def getObjFunc(self):
        return self.objfunc

    def setColors(self, colors):
        # Q1: How to initialize self.colors to size of colors? Index out of range now as self.colors has zero length.
        self.colors = list(colors)    
        for i in range(0, len(colors)):
            # Q2: Is this the right way to copy class?
            self.colors[i]= copy.deepcopy(colors[i])   

    def getColors(self):
        return self.colors

def funcA():

    br = []
    br.append(BestResult())

    colors = []
    colors.append(Color())
    colors[0].num = 5
    colors[0].nodelist = [10, 20 , 30 , 40, 50]

    colors.append(Color())
    colors[1].num = 2
    colors[1].nodelist = [6, 7]

    br[0].setObjFunc(-100)

    # Q3: How to set colors[0] and colors[1] into br's colors?          
    br[0].setColors(colors)       

    print("br=%d" %br[0].getObjFunc())
    # Q4 How to retrieve each elements of (num & nodelist) in br[0].colors
    res = br[0].getColors()
    print res[0].num
    print res[0].nodelist
    print res[1].num
    print res[1].nodelist   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    funcA()
```

Comment: Your example is not trivial and your question is not clear.  You may wish to clarify.

Comment: +1 Who8MyLunch, it looks like you're doing what you're talking about and storing the highest result with setObjFunc, but I don't entirely understand what you're looking to do with finding the "Best" result. What qualifies a result as "Best"? And is this to take place when you're setting new colors in set_colors or has this already been taken care of in setObjFunc with self.objfunc?

Comment: Don't use `__*__` for your own attributes. That namespace is reserved for Python